# Swipe Detection and Click Detection

Tags: javascript, java, android

I am currently building an app on Android. Now please keep in mind I am quite the amateur but I have been able to figure out most of what I need to figure out for my very simple app. But this issue has been frustrating me and I can't find a solution.

For background, I've been using swipe right and left to "scroll" through different text options. However, I want to change a completely different text field every time I click.

For example, textview1 changes when I swipe and textview2 changes every time I click. But they are on the same page.

My code works for swiping, but when I click, it performs the same function as if I swiped right.

Here is the code I am using, any help on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated:

```
final float len = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi/6;

linear1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                float initX;
                float initY;
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch(event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            initX = event.getX();
                            initY = event.getY();
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            initX -= event.getX();
                            initY -= event.getY();
                            if (initY > len) {

//Logic For Swipe Right


                            } else if(initY < -len) {

               //Logic For Swipe Left   

                            } else {
                                if(initY < 0) initY = -initY;
                                if(initX < 0) initX = -initX;
                                if(initX <= len/4 && initY <= len/4) {

 //Logic For OnClick   

                                }
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
});
```

Another issue which is a minor complaint is that it is detecting up and down swipes as well. With the down swipe doing what the right swipe is supposed to do and the up swipe doing what the left swipe is supposed to do. I only want left and right swipe detection, not up and down at all.

Thank you all in advance! Hope you can help this noob!

Comment: Stick to a single question at a time. Please don't tack "another issue" onto your question.

Comment: Okay, I apologize. Thank you for letting me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement an [onClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener) for the click event. onTouchListener will not suffice for this case (as it is intended to handle a completely different event type).

*(Updated)* It will be something like this:

```
linear1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do things here, this will be run when the element is clicked
    }
});
```

*Updated (as per request):* Your onTouchListener should (afaict) contain this now:

```
linear1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                float initX;
                float initY;
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch(event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            initX = event.getX();
                            initY = event.getY();
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            initX -= event.getX();
                            initY -= event.getY();
                            if (initY > len) {
                                //Logic For Swipe Right
                            } else if(initY < -len) {
                                //Logic For Swipe Left   
                            }
                            break;
                     }
                     return true;
                }
});
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: I apologize if this is a stupid question, but I add that code that you put as is? I am not familiar with the onClickListener. I am very inexperienced with code.

Comment: @Ammer12 updated my answer to be a little more concise, hope that helps you understand

Comment: That makes more sense, thank you for making it easier for me to understand. Do I need to remove any part of my original code? Because I tried it and it is still performing the swipe right function when I click on linear1.

Comment: You can remove the entire `else` statement where you have the comment that has the comment : `'//Logic For OnClick'`

Comment: Okay, so to confirm, I would remove it from else { to } } right before the "break;"? i.e. 'else {
                                if(initY < 0) initY = -initY;
                                if(initX < 0) initX = -initX;
                                if(initX <= len/4 && initY <= len/4) {

 //Logic For OnClick   

                                }
                            }'

Comment: I'll updated my answer to show you, although I do recommend you watch some Youtube videos to help become more familiar (theNewBoston's videos were great for me when I started: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBsvRxJJOzG4r4k_zLKrnxl)

Comment: I watched the youtube videos about gestures and he was talking about the return true at very end. I switched it to return false and it is now working!!! Does that make sense? I mean it's working so I guess I can't complain but I just wanted to see if that makes sense or not lol

Answer (score 1):

In your `onTouch()` method you could check that the origin of the event is touching your textview2 TextView. In this case, ignore the event and let your textview2's onClick() method handle it:

```
linear1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                float initX;
                float initY;
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    if (v == textview2) {
                        return;
                    }

                    switch(event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            initX = event.getX();
                            initY = event.getY();
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            initX -= event.getX();
                            initY -= event.getY();
                            if (initY > len) {
                                //Logic For Swipe Right
                            } else if(initY < -len) {
                                //Logic For Swipe Left   
                            }
                            break;
                     }
                     return true;
                }
});
```

Comment: I am trying to code it so that anywhere on linear1 that I touch it will change textview2 and anywhere on linear1 that I swipe it will change textview1. Is the code you referenced accomplishing that? Sorry but I think this whole coding thing is way over my head so I apologize if my questions seem nooby lol

Comment: I've updated the code so that when use touches your linear1 component, the event is ignored

Comment: it is still not working could you please explain this to me a bit more so i can figure this out? I'm getting desperate here

Comment: You've accepted an answer. Are you still looking for help ?